# Kotlin - return new inserted id from Room database using Persistence Room:runtime lib

Tags: android, kotlin, persistence, android-room

I am trying to insert user record in Room database using Kotlin and It's working perfectly.

And now I want to return newly inserted record id to check if a record is successfully inserted or not in Room database.

But when I am applying Long return type in the insert method and run the code that time I get the following error.

> error: Method returns long but it should return one of the following:
>   `void, long[], java.lang.Long[], java.util.List<java.lang.Long>`. If
>   you want to return the list of row ids from the query, your insertion
>   method can receive only 1 parameter.
>
> ```
> public abstract long insertUser(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
> ```

I am using this lib.

> implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
>
> ```
> kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
> ```

Here is my insert query.

```
@Insert
fun insertUser(vararg userRegistrationEntity: UserRegistrationEntity):Long;
```

Here is my addAsyncTask where I am inserting a record in Room database

```
private fun userRegistration(userRegistrationEntity: UserRegistrationEntity) {
        addAsyncTask(appDatabase!!).execute(userRegistrationEntity) 
    }

    private class addAsyncTask constructor(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) : AsyncTask<UserRegistrationEntity, Void, Long>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: UserRegistrationEntity): Long? {
           // val a = appDatabase.userRegistrationDao().addUser(params[0]);
            val newReturnId = appDatabase.userRegistrationDao().insertUser(params[0]);
            return newReturnId
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Long?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Log.d("value", result.toString()) 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're inserting multiple entities, you can only get their IDs back in an array or list, for example, like this:

```
@Insert
fun insertUsers(vararg userRegistrationEntities: UserRegistrationEntity): List<Long>
```

If you insert one entity at a time, you can get its ID back as a `Long`:

```
@Insert
fun insertUser(userRegistrationEntity: UserRegistrationEntity): Long
```

Comment: when I'm using List<Long> it's working but however when I use Long as you said for one entity It gives me the above error.

Comment: You need to remove `vararg` and only insert one element if you want to use `Long`, as I've shown above.

Comment: @zsmb13 what would be the return value when the insert is failed on some case where I am expecting single Long value ?

Comment: I think you'd get an SQLException or something similar if the insertion failed.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert)

A method annotated with the @Insert annotation can return:

```
long for single insert operation
long[] or Long[] or List<Long> for multiple insert operations
void if you don't care about the inserted id(s)
```