# Kotlin Exposed ORM - id not in record set

Tags: kotlin, orm, ktor

New to Kotlin Exposed and trying to store data using IdTable and getting errror 'id is not in record set.' Below is the code using

```
object GeoLocationModel : IdTable<Long>("geolocation_pos") {
    val code = long("code").primaryKey()
    val createdAt = datetime("created_at").clientDefault { currentUtc() }
    val updatedAt = datetime("updated_at").nullable()
    val createdBy = varchar("created_by", 255).clientDefault { authenticatedUser() }
    val updatedBy = varchar("updated_by", 255).nullable()
    val uuid = uuid("uuid").autoGenerate().uniqueIndex()
    val latitude: Column<Double> = double("latitude")
    val longitude: Column<Double> = double("longitude")
    val pincode: Column<Long> = long("pincode")
    override val id: Column<EntityID<Long>> =  code.entityId()
}

object GeoLocationModel : IdTable<Long>("geolocation_pos") {
    val code = long("code").primaryKey()
    val createdAt = datetime("created_at").clientDefault { currentUtc() }
    val updatedAt = datetime("updated_at").nullable()
    val createdBy = varchar("created_by", 255).clientDefault { authenticatedUser() }
    val updatedBy = varchar("updated_by", 255).nullable()
    val uuid = uuid("uuid").autoGenerate().uniqueIndex()
    val latitude: Column<Double> = double("latitude")
    val longitude: Column<Double> = double("longitude")
    val pincode: Column<Long> = long("pincode")
    override val id: Column<EntityID<Long>> =  code.entityId()
}

Insertion of data for **geolocation_pos** table

 val geolocationId = GeoLocationModel.insert {
                it[code] = nextSequenceVal()
                it[latitude] = 28.550667
                it[longitude] = 77.268952
                it[pincode] = xxxxxx
            } get GeoLocationModel.id
```

MySQL database is not able to save throws an error stating

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.GeoLocationModel.code is not in record set
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ResultRow.getRaw(ResultRow.kt:53) ~[exposed-core-0.21.1.jar:na]
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ResultRow.get(ResultRow.kt:18) ~[exposed-core-0.21.1.jar:na]
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.InsertStatement.get(InsertStatement.kt:20) ~[exposed-core-0.21.1.jar:na]
```

Generated SQL

```
INSERT INTO geolocation_pos (code, created_at, created_by, latitude, longitude, pincode, updated_at, updated_by, uuid) VALUES (106, 'xxxxxxx', 'xxx', 28.550667, 77.268952, xxxxx, NULL, NULL, 'dd6aaf69-5324-4fac-9271-5c099957e06b')
```

Please can anyone help me resolving the issue.

Comment: If ID is auto generated; to get the ID of a record it should be saved in the database first. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51204743/175554