# kotlin Not sure how to handle insert method's return type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

i am developing an android application using kotlin and room library.  when i try to get the id of the inserted item i am getting the following error

Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract java.lang.Object insertReceipt(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

i have tried other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204685/kotlin-return-new-inserted-id-from-room-database-using-persistence-roomruntim) but it is not working

here is my code

**Receipt.kt**

```
@Entity
data class Receipt(
    @ColumnInfo() val receipt_timestamp: Timestamp,
    @ColumnInfo() val receipt_items: Int,
    @ColumnInfo() val receipt_total_price: BigDecimal
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var receiptNo: Int = 0
}
```

**ReceiptDao.kt**

```
@Insert()
    suspend fun insertReceipt(receipt: Receipt): Int
```

**ReceiptRepository.kt**

```
suspend fun insertReceipt(receipt: Receipt): Int{
        return receiptDAO.insertReceipt(receipt)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room - Get the id of new inserted row with auto-generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364240/android-room-get-the-id-of-new-inserted-row-with-auto-generate)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you cannot get the id like this. You can get an id with this function but it will not be the one you want.

cf: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert the id returned is an internal id used by sqlite.

To achieve what you want, you need something like:

```
@Query("SELECT receiptNo FROM receipt WHERE receipt_timestamp = :receipt_timestamp AND receipt_items = : receipt_items AND receipt_total_price = :receipt_total_price LIMIT 1")
fun getId(receipt_timestamp: Timestamp, receipt_items: Int, receipt_total_price: BigDecimal): Int
```

Answer (score 1):

A method annotated with the @Insert annotation can return:

> ```
>     long for single insert operation
>     long[] or Long[] or List for multiple insert operations
>     void if you don't care about the inserted id(s)
> ```

So you must change your return type of insertReceipt from Int to Long:

```
return receiptDAO.insertReceipt(receipt).toLong()
```